# downloading files using dropbox url android

Tags: android, dropbox, android-download-manager

I am trying to download files using dropbox url. I copied a code from [Download a file with Android, and showing the progress in a ProgressDialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3028306/download-a-file-with-android-and-showing-the-progress-in-a-progressdialog) which uses DownloadManager class.

```
    public void downloadFromDropBoxUrl(View view) {
        //verfying if the downloadmanager is available first.
        if (isDownloadManagerAvailable(getApplication())) {
            String url = "https://www.dropbox.com/s/m4z5u9qstxdtbc3/AllExams22.pdf?dl=0";
            DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));
            request.setDescription("Some descrition");
            request.setTitle("Some title");
// in order for this if to run, you must use the android 3.2 to compile your app
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
                request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
                request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
            }
            request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, "my-map.pdf");

// get download service and enqueue file
            DownloadManager manager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
            manager.enqueue(request);
        }
    }
    public static boolean isDownloadManagerAvailable(Context context) {

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

It is working on achiving direct files with urls but this time I am trying to do it with dropbox share links but its not working out. I don't want to connect to dropbox api. I think it is useless. Is there any way I can download files directly from the dropbox url?

Comment: For reference, here's the help article that documents the "dl" and "raw" parameters on shared links: https://www.dropbox.com/help/201

Answer (score 6, accepted):

just replace

```
String url = "https://www.dropbox.com/s/m4z5u9qstxdtbc3/AllExams22.pdf?dl=0";
```

by:

```
String url = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/m4z5u9qstxdtbc3/AllExams22.pdf";
```

Then:

```
final DownloadTask downloadTask = new DownloadTask(YourActivity.this);
downloadTask.execute(url);
```

Comment: i didnot tried this one but i fixed my problem by changing dl=0 to dl=1

Answer (score 1):

Please see this link on how to download a shared file from Dropbox

https://blogs.dropbox.com/developers/2013/08/programmatically-download-content-from-share-links/